# Deleting SPAM found in SQL query results, using jQuery

Tags: sql, string

My website is getting spammed with entries such as:

```
 <a style="text-decoration:none" href="/amoxicillin-kamagra-shop">.</a>
```

I want to filter those out with jQuery, as there are too many to do it manually through the UI (wayyy too tedious). The challenge is determining the SPAM-matching criteria, such as the HTML tag info.

So, for example, if I determine that most or all spam is of the form

`<a style="text-decoration:none` ... `>.</a>`

How would I delete those entries with jQuery?

Comment: it is so costly to remove string from the database after adding it , first try not to add that string

Comment: You mean to say that you are storing some input data from your user on the website in a database column and you want to remove junk characters like full stop, angle brackets etc for the already existing data. Is it?

Comment: Which DBMS that you use? (mysql, sql-server, ...)

Answer (score 0):

DELETE from yourtable WHERE string like '<%a style="text-decoration:none%>.%'

Comment: With this query, he may probably lose lots of valuable records as well!